# CSS Responsive change width in 100%

Tags: css, responsive-design

ISSUE SUMMARY:
 Hi,

I just purchased Jomsocial + Template Socialize. I use RSForm for my landing page.
I have an image on left and the form on the right side on desktop view.

When I reduce browser to simulate Responsive view, the text come under image but has a width of 50%. This is the width necessary for destopview.

So I add some lines in /templates/socialize/css/template.css

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
.div_image_homepage_right {
      width: 100% !important;
   }
}
```

BUT it doesn't work. width stay 50% instead of 100%. I tried with Chrome & Firefox.

Please see screenshot for better understanding.

Someone has an idea how to fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    .div_image_homepage_right {
      width: 100% !important;
     }
    }
```

I think the underlying issue is using `max-device-width` vs plain old `max-width`. Using the "device" keyword targets physical dimension of the screen, not the width of the browser window.

For example:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    /* STYLES HERE for DEVICES with physical max-screen width of 480px */
}
```

Versus

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    /* STYLES HERE for BROWSER WINDOWS with a max-width of 480px. This will work on desktops when the window is narrowed.  */
}
```